# Convert Select Columns in Pandas Dataframe to Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to convert everything but the first column of a pandas dataframe into a numpy array. For some reason using the `columns=` parameter of `DataFrame.to_matrix()` is not working.

df:

```
  viz  a1_count  a1_mean     a1_std
0   n         3        2   0.816497
1   n         0      NaN        NaN 
2   n         2       51  50.000000
```

I tried `X=df.as_matrix(columns=[df[1:]])` but this yields an array of all `NaN`s

Comment: You are passing rows not column names

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `columns` parameter accepts a collection of column names.  You're passing a list containing a dataframe with two rows:

```
>>> [df[1:]]
[  viz  a1_count  a1_mean  a1_std
1   n         0      NaN     NaN
2   n         2       51      50]
>>> df.as_matrix(columns=[df[1:]])
array([[ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan]])
```

Instead, pass the column names you want:

```
>>> df.columns[1:]
Index(['a1_count', 'a1_mean', 'a1_std'], dtype='object')
>>> df.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[1:])
array([[  3.      ,   2.      ,   0.816497],
       [  0.      ,        nan,        nan],
       [  2.      ,  51.      ,  50.      ]])
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling I was missing something trivial.

Comment: I would just like to add that as_matrix is being removed in a future version and the message I received said to use .values instead.

Comment: as_matrix is now deprecated.

Comment: Try using `values` instead of `as_matrix`

Comment: Starting from version 0.24.0 just use `to_numpy` method on your column (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy)

Answer (score 121):

the easy way is the "values" property `df.iloc[:,1:].values`

```
a=df.iloc[:,1:]
b=df.iloc[:,1:].values

print(type(df))
print(type(a))
print(type(b))
```

so, you can get type

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Or if you want to extract the columns by name instead of position: `df[['a1_count', 'a1_mean', 'a1_std']].values`

Answer (score 79):

Please use the [Pandas `to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) method. Below is an example--

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2], "B":[3, 4], "C":[5, 6]})
>>> df 
    A  B  C
 0  1  3  5
 1  2  4  6
>>> s_array = df[["A", "B", "C"]].to_numpy()
>>> s_array

array([[1, 3, 5],
   [2, 4, 6]]) 

>>> t_array = df[["B", "C"]].to_numpy() 
>>> print (t_array)

[[3 5]
 [4 6]]
```

Hope this helps. You can select any number of columns using

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df1 = df[columns]
```

Then apply `to_numpy()` method.

Answer (score 16):

Hope this easy one liner helps:

```
cols_as_np = df[df.columns[1:]].to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way for converting to Numpy Array is using '.to_numpy(self, dtype=None, copy=False)'. It is new in version 0.24.0.[Refrence](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy)

You can also use '.array'.[Refrence](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values)

Pandas .as_matrix deprecated since version 0.23.0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of .as_matrix(), use .values, because the first one was deprecated. Here is the contribution:

['DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102281/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-as-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

#### The fastest and easiest way is to use `.as_matrix()`. One short line:

```
df.iloc[:,[1,2,3]].as_matrix()
```

#### Gives:

```
array([[3, 2, 0.816497],
   [0, 'NaN', 'NaN'],
   [2, 51, 50.0]], dtype=object)
```

#### By using indices of the columns, you can use this code for any dataframe with different column names.

Here are the steps for your example:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['viz', 'a1_count', 'a1_mean', 'a1_std']
index = [0,1,2]
vals = {'viz': ['n','n','n'], 'a1_count': [3,0,2], 'a1_mean': [2,'NaN', 51], 'a1_std': [0.816497, 'NaN', 50.000000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=columns, index=index)
```

Gives:

```
   viz  a1_count a1_mean    a1_std
0   n         3       2  0.816497
1   n         0     NaN       NaN
2   n         2      51        50
```

Then:

```
x1 = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3]].as_matrix()
```

Gives:

```
array([[3, 2, 0.816497],
   [0, 'NaN', 'NaN'],
   [2, 51, 50.0]], dtype=object)
```

Where x1 is `numpy.ndarray`.