# Pandas concatenate columns values as list across columns and then dump the whole dataframe into numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with 10 columns with each elements as list of length 40.How can i convert them into numpy array of shape (-1,400) .
[column (click this link to see the column)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5xFO.jpg)

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and don't only provide links to images. In particular, the dtype of the dataframe is important here.

Comment: Look at `df.to_numpy()`.  That's the array created from the frame.  A clear idea of it's shape, dtype, and nature of the elements is required before you can consolidate into a more compact array.

Comment: Array shape of (-1,400)? What does it mean?

Comment: This question has already been asked. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789160/convert-select-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array. Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: @desertnaut  The quoted link does not completely solve this question.  Need to concatenate the lists within columns.

Comment: @SeaBean OK, I reopened it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`numpy.concatenate()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) + [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
import numpy as np

df.apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x), axis=1).to_numpy()
```

### Test Run

Define a dataframe with 3 rows 10 columns each element of a list of length 40:

```
data = [[list(range(40))] * 10] * 3
cols = list(range(10))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

**Result:**

Shape of whole extraction:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x), axis=1).to_numpy().shape

(3,)
```

Shape of each row:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x), axis=1).to_numpy()[0].shape

(400,)
```