# Fastest way in numpy to get distance of product of n pairs in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, bigdata

I have `N` number of points, for example:

```py
A = [2, 3]
B = [3, 4]
C = [3, 3]
.
.
.
```

And they're in an array like so:

```py
arr = np.array([[2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 3]])
```

I need as output all pairwise distances in `BFS (Breadth First Search)` order to track which distance is which, like: `A->B, A->C, B->C`. For the above example data, the result would be `[1.41, 1.0, 1.0]`.

EDIT: I have to accomplish it with numpy or core libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest pairwise distance metric in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277982/fastest-pairwise-distance-metric-in-python)

Comment: Unfortunately, I found solutions like this a lot before I wrote, usually people want distance of 1 dimensional variables like in linked topic. Or just calculate N-dimensional pair of points, not N points of N-dimensions (or 2-dimension in that case) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative method, but similar to [**ddejohn** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72218182/13394817), we can use `np.triu_indices` which return just the upper triangular indices in the matrix, which may be more memory-efficient:

```
np.linalg.norm(arr - arr[:, None], axis=-1)[np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0], 1)]
```

This doesn't need additional modules like flattening and indexing. Its performance is similar to the aforementioned answer for large data (e.g. you can check it by `arr = np.random.rand(10000, 2)` on colab, which will be done near 4.6 s for both; It may beats the `np.triu` and `flatten` in larger data).

I have tested the memory usage one time by memory-profiler as follows, but it must be checked again if it be important in terms of memory usage (I'm not sure):

[image]

### Update:

I have tried to limit the calculations just to the upper triangle, that speed the code up 2 to 3 times on the tested arrays. As array size grows, the performance difference between this loop and the previous methods by `np.triu_indices` or `np.triu` grows and be more obvious:

```
ind = np.arange(arr.shape[0] - 1)
sub_ind = ind + 1
result = np.zeros(sub_ind.sum())
j = 0
for i in range(ind.shape[0]):
    result[j:j+ind[-1-i]+1] = np.linalg.norm(arr[ind[i]] - arr[sub_ind[i]:], axis=-1)
    j += ind[-1-i]+1
```

**Also, through this way, the memory consumption is reduced at least `~x4`. So, this method made it possible to work on larger arrays and more quickly.**

### [Benchmarks:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zzEm6gMc-3u6aDil2YsFLcD0_ZwqCyTt?usp=sharing)

```
# arr = np.random.rand(100, 2)
100 loops, best of 5: 459  µs per loop     (ddejohns --> np.triu & np.flatten) 
100 loops, best of 5: 528  µs per loop     (mine --> np.triu_indices) 
100 loops, best of 5: 1.42 ms per loop     (This method)
--------------------------------------
# arr = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
10  loops, best of 5: 49.9 ms per loop
10  loops, best of 5: 49.7 ms per loop
10  loops, best of 5: 30.4 ms per loop      (~x1.7)  The fastest
--------------------------------------
# arr = np.random.rand(10000, 2)
2   loops, best of 5: 4.56 s  per loop
2   loops, best of 5: 4.6  s  per loop
2   loops, best of 5: 1.85 s  per loop      (~x2.5)  The fastest
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use it, SciPy has a function for this:

```py
In [2]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

In [3]: pdist(arr)
Out[3]: array([1.41421356, 1.        , 1.        ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a numpy-only solution (fair warning: it requires a lot of memory, unlike `pdist`)...

```py
dists = np.triu(np.linalg.norm(arr - arr[:, None], axis=-1)).flatten()
dists = dists[dists != 0]
```

Demo:

```py
In [4]: arr = np.array([[2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 3], [5, 2], [4, 5]])

In [5]: pdist(arr)
Out[5]:
array([1.41421356, 1.        , 3.16227766, 2.82842712, 1.        ,
       2.82842712, 1.41421356, 2.23606798, 2.23606798, 3.16227766])

In [6]: dists = np.triu(np.linalg.norm(arr - arr[:, None], axis=-1)).flatten()

In [7]: dists = dists[dists != 0]

In [8]: dists
Out[8]:
array([1.41421356, 1.        , 3.16227766, 2.82842712, 1.        ,
       2.82842712, 1.41421356, 2.23606798, 2.23606798, 3.16227766])
```

Timings (with the solution above wrapped in a function called `triu`):

```py
In [9]: %timeit pdist(arr)
7.27 µs ± 738 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit triu(arr)
25.5 µs ± 4.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is nice, the only issue is that it computes also the other part of the matrix which is not needed, so it's probably a bit slower

Comment: Yep, about 3.5x slower for a small array. Since we're dealing with combinations I'm not sure there's a better way than generating all pairwise distances and then taking the upper triangular.

Comment: Idk if there is a way to avoid calculation of other part, but it should be fast enough as my iterative solution was over 20 times slower, thank you very much I've been struggling with it for long.

Comment: @Guaz , I have updated my answer by limiting the calculation to just the upper triangle which will improve the performance at least 2 times on large data. Please check it.